# How can I resolve this error:java.net.UnknownHostException: android.clients.google.com?

Tags: android-emulator, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am running a simple project on Titanium studio in android emulator..but I get `java.net.UnknownHostException: android.clients.google.com` error on console..How do I resolve it??

Comment: Did you get internet permissions? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427487/java-unknown-host-exception

Comment: Titanium usually does this automatically. Similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925028/titanium-build-error-andrioid)

Comment: ok..error is removed by changeing emulator..thanks for comments..