# Titanium build error: Android

Tags: titanium

Facing one issue continuously since last few days. Whenever I build anything to see the stuff in Emulator getting below error:

> [ERROR][CheckinTask( 169)] Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0) 
>   [ERROR][CheckinTask( 169)] java.net.UnknownHostException: android.clients.google.com

After this error in logs emulator doesn't respond properly. My old code even kitchen sink demo not working though it was working properly before.

Comment: please post a bit of code where this error occurs

Comment: I don't think it is a code based error.  He is saying it happens on several different projects.

Comment: @Martin But it would allow to reproduce and file a bug report. And it's possible to check when this error occurs? In a WebView? Loading a remote image? Something completely different?

Comment: @ Martin thanks but nothing happened. 
I have tried clean build but still getting below errors

See Below Logs what I am getting
[WARN][PackageManager(   60)] Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
[WARN][PackageManager(   60)] Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x1be45)
[ERROR][CheckinTask(  167)] Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0)
[ERROR][CheckinTask(  167)] java.net.UnknownHostException: android.clients.google.com

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I'm constantly battling the Android emulator trying to deploy and debug with it.  When things break down and I can't figure out why, I clean my project.  I then attempt to twice debug it to the emulator.  I'm not sure why, but the first attempt seems to fail often.  If I still can't connect I close the emulator and then clean the project again.  I then try to compile and debug.  If that still doesn't work I close everything down and reboot the system.

Once I have it working I can usually keep it going for a while.

Comment: We will typically build and debug on actual devices rather than deal with the emulator.  Too much of a hassle.